# Permission issue with simple appveyor script

Tags: continuous-integration, command, appveyor

So I have this very simple script which just tries to create a text file and then read it.

```
version: 1.0.{build}-{branch}

shallow_clone: true

environment:
matrix:
    - APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
    TOOLSET: msvc-14.1
    ARCH: x86_64
    - APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
    TOOLSET: msvc-14.1
    ARCH: x86

install:
- if %ARCH% == x86 ( set TRIPLET=x86-windows ) else ( set TRIPLET=x64-windows )
- if %ARCH% == x86 ( set AM=32 ) else ( set AM=64 )
- git clone -b master --depth 1 https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git boost-root
- cd boost-root

build: off

test_script:
- set PATH=%ADDPATH%%PATH%
- |-
    set VCPKG=%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\..\vcpkg\installed\%TRIPLET%
    set "CHUNK=^<include^>%VCPKG%\include ^<search^>%VCPKG%\lib"
    echo using zlib : : %CHUNK% ; > config.jam
    echo using libjpeg : : %CHUNK% ; >> config.jam
    echo using libpng : : ^<name^>libpng16 %CHUNK% ; >> config.jam
    echo using libtiff : : %CHUNK% ; >> config.jam
    more config.jam
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Cannot access file C:\projects\gil\boost-root\config.jam
Command exited with code 1
```

Is there something obviously wrong that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think `set "CHUNK=^<include^>%VCPKG%\include ^<search^>%VCPKG%\lib"` breaks something in environment variables. Try moving first `"` after `=`, like `set CHUNK="^<include^>%VCPKG%\include ^<search^>%VCPKG%\lib"`.

Comment: This is not quite right. Here is why: https://pastebin.com/raw/7HBY3ppW